# Como ler um inteiro sem limite de digitos em C

Tags: c, variáveis, lista

Tem alguma forma de ler um inteiro do teclado sem controlo de limite de dígitos. Tipo eu preciso de passar um numero gigante via teclado para uma variável e depois passar os todos os dígitos desse numero para os nos de uma  lista. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Sim, leia em buffer controlado (talvez apenas 100 dígitos por vez?) e mande para uma estrutura de dados chamada `BigInt`.

Comment: como assim? uso a funcao fgets()

Comment: Essa pergunta já passou por aqui, infelizmente não a consegui encontrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um *buffer* de `chars` grande o bastantes para acomodar os inteiros como uma string.

Operações com números inteiros grandes podem ser feitas com a utilização de uma biblioteca da `GNU` chamada [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/).

Segue um exemplo onde os dois argumentos (inteiros grandes) passados para a `main()` são multiplicados e seu resultado exibido na tela:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN    (128)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char res[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];

    mpz_t a, b, c;

    mpz_init(a);
    mpz_init(b);
    mpz_init(c);

    mpz_set_str( a, argv[1], 10 );
    mpz_set_str( b, argv[2], 10 );

    mpz_mul( c, a, b );

    mpz_get_str( res, 10, c );

    printf("%s\n", res );

    mpz_clear(a);
    mpz_clear(b);
    mpz_clear(c);

    return 0;
}
```

compilando:

```
$ gcc -lgmp -Wall bigintmul.c -o bigintmul
```

Testando:

```
$ ./bigintmul 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 9876543219876543219876543219876543210
```

Saída:

```
12193263124676116335924401657049230176967230591384377380136092059011263526900
```

Checando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]